How is important cache for a backup NAS storage?
I'm working on a new nas to store veeam backups of some VMs.
I will use some magnetic disks and my doubt is about optional ssd cache disks.
I was wondering if it is important the cache layer, generally I know few cache disks is not a bad idea, but in this case I would like to know if it is recommended or not very useful.
As far as I know the cache is used to absorb few small operations or repeated operations in same sectors. In a vm backup scenario I expect a massive write ops and cache layer will be shortly filled and became almost unuseful.
Am I right or am I wrong?

Well, a small cache drive that has the same speed as all spinning drives can have a positive impact on performance, especially for Veeam, i.e., it can align the request for optimum transfer beforehand.

Does this answer your question? Can you help me with my capacity planning?

Just benchmark and decide.

It depends.
During backup, large contiguous files are written and a flash cache isn't of much use. It might be able to optimize concurrently running jobs - depending on the caching mode and algorithms, but the volume of writes is going to wear down a normal SSD pretty quickly.
For VM recovery to production storage, there isn't much benefit either. However, if you plan to use Veeam Instant Recovery, especially without immediate migration, then a reasonably sized flash cache can make quite a difference.

Thanks, I didn't think about Veeam Instant Recovery
